# Selenium can't find non-visible element within scrollable div even though it is in the source

Tags: python, selenium

So I want Selenium to click the below shown element (`symbol="DKNG"`) which upon page launch is not within the viewport but in a scrollable div and thus also in the source.

```
<span class="inner-EJ_LFrif symbolNameText-EJ_LFrif">DKNG</span>
```

This approach works in case the element is visible right from page launch:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ec.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[text()='" + symbol + "']"))).click()
```

But the desired case if the element is not visible on viewport on page launch doesn't work:

```
# Search the target element
target_element_in_panel = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[text()='" + symbol + "']")

actions = ActionChains(driver)
actions.move_to_element(target_element_in_panel).perform()
target_element_in_panel.click()

# returns -> selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[text()='DKNG']"}
```

The source page requires login (free content), here's the snip. Target element is in the scrollable div (yellow highlighted).

[image]

Comment: Maybe you can try `WebdriverWait until element is visible`? anyway, is it possible to share the website link for inspection?

Comment: @AnandGautam I added a screen, site requires login. Note: When driver is running and I manually scroll a bit within that div the driver finds and clicks the element even though it is not visible still. Why's that?

Comment: Is the element present in the DOM before the scroll? or is it lazy loading and the element is added after the scroll?

Comment: @Guy it is present before the scroll, just double-checked by searching the source for `DKNG`

Comment: Well the error suggests that either it's lazy loading (did you check the DOM in a fresh page where you never scrolled the table?) or a timing issue, try adding few seconds sleep to see if the driver still can't find the element. In this case `ec.presence_of_element_located` should work.

Comment: @Guy checked the DOM in a fresh page load before scrolling, the element is present. Also added 10 sec of sleep before kicking off the element query. It works for elements that are visible from the very start in this div like e.g. "TSLA" in the pic above.

Comment: solved it: For whatever reason a small cookie pop-up prevented that Selenium could find the element. This was not the case for visible elements in the same parent though, weird.